# How to remove some items up to a certain index from the end in python?

Tags: python, list, loops

Say there is a list. `XYZ = ['a','b','c','d','e']` . Now I want to remove up to `'c'` from the end using a loop.Please help if anyone have any idea.

Comment: why `using a loop`? is it homework?

Comment: I want to delete at a time actually.

Comment: Does your list contain repeated elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> XYZ[:XYZ.index('c')]
['a', 'b']
# to keep 'c'
# >>> XYZ[:XYZ.index('c')+1]
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Here, we are not deleting. we are slicing the list as required.

To delete elements from list,

```
>>> del XYZ[XYZ.index('c')+1:]
>>> XYZ
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**Edit-1:**

To work with special case as mentioned by @Austin in comments,
for the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

We need to do as shown below,

```
>>> XYZ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> XYZ.reverse()
>>> del XYZ[:XYZ.index('c')]
>>> XYZ.reverse()
>>> XYZ
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201146/discussion-on-answer-by-shaik-moeed-how-to-remove-some-items-up-to-a-certain-ind).

Answer (score 1):

I would go about a `next` approach which avoids the double reversing as in the other answer:

```
XYZ = ['a','b','c','d','c','e','g']

if 'c' in XYZ:
    XYZ = XYZ[:-next((i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(XYZ)) if x == 'c'))]

# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
```

Comment: As this is a list slicing, it won't match OP expected output. As OP mentioned in my comments, he wants to delete elements. I guess adding `del` as mentioned by @JonCelements in my comments or re-initialize `XYZ` value will make this solution complete.